# Using ArrayList in C# to create a calculator type web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I need to use ArrayList to make a calculator type application for a web page. The calculator calculates how many calories the user has burned based on a couple different things.

There are three textboxes that the user enters value into. They are labeled: Activity, Weight, and Duration. In the the Acitivity box, the user enters an activity (either canoeing, fishing, golfing, hunting, running, or walking). In the weight box, the user enters a weight. The duration is how long the user performed the selected activity in minutes. Each activity burns a different amount of calories depending on the weight entered. For example, if the user enters Canoeing for the activity, and 120 for the weight, and 60 for the time, the desired output will be 236 calories burned. However, if the user enters 150 for the weight, the outcome will be 281.

It's a little bit confusing, but basically the calories burned vary depending on the weight of the person. The three ranges are 0-130, 131-155, 156-180, and 181-205.

Can anyone help me out? I know it might be hard to understand so let me know if anything needs clarification. I'll post the code I have so far below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

    ArrayList rangeSmallest = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList rangeSmall = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList rangeBig = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList rangeBiggest = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList activity = new ArrayList();

void Page_Load()
    {

        rangeSmallest.Add(236);
        rangeSmallest.Add(177);
        rangeSmallest.Add(266);
        rangeSmallest.Add(295);
        rangeSmallest.Add(472);
        rangeSmallest.Add(148);

        rangeSmall.Add(281);
        rangeSmall.Add(211);
        rangeSmall.Add(317);
        rangeSmall.Add(352);
        rangeSmall.Add(563);
        rangeSmall.Add(176);

        rangeBig.Add(327);
        rangeBig.Add(245);
        rangeBig.Add(368);
        rangeBig.Add(409);
        rangeBig.Add(654);
        rangeBig.Add(204);

        rangeBiggest.Add(372);
        rangeBiggest.Add(279);
        rangeBiggest.Add(419);
        rangeBiggest.Add(465);
        rangeBiggest.Add(745);
        rangeBiggest.Add(233);

        activity.Add("Canoeing");
        activity.Add("Fishing");
        activity.Add("Golfing");
        activity.Add("Hunting");
        activity.Add("Running");
        activity.Add("Walking");
    }

    void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



}

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
 Activity:   <asp:TextBox ID="txtActivity" runat="server" /><br />
 Weight: <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeight" runat="server" /><br />
 Duration (in minutes): <asp:TextBox ID="txtDuration" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Calories Burned"
    OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblCaloriesBurned" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is 2013. Please don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs the old days when C# doesn't have _generics_. You can use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is exactly. Also why are you using multiple Collections when you could create an object ("ExerciseActivity") which contains the name and the other details? You could have just one Collection and much much neater code.

Comment: I understand that ArrayList is essentially obsolete but I need to use it for an assignment, and I just want some help understanding the logic behind it, I suppose. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ArrayLists (Since it was specifically asked for. It is in no way the best practice, nor does it make use of OOP). I'm keeping it as simple as possible

```
public double CalculateCalories(string text, double mass, double time)
{
    int index = -1;

    //First we find the index we're interested in
    for(int i=0; i < activity.count; i++)
    {
        string act = activity[i].ToString();

        //If we match the string perfectly, then we know the index
        if (act.Equals(text))
        {
            index = i;
        }

    }

    if (index.Equals(-1))
    {
        //error - throw some sort of exception
    }

    //Now that we know the index, we'll determine which arrayList we look for

    double calorieCount  = 0;

    if (mass < 130)
    {
        //take from the small one
        calorieCount = rangeSmall[index];
    }
    else if (//Follow the same pattern)
    {
        //
    }

    //Then multiply it by time somehow - depending on how your multiplier is set up

    return time*calorieCount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an object which I'll call ExerciseActivity

```
public class ExerciseActivity
{
    //Hold the name, and the calorie details in here
    String Name {get;set;}
    double lowCalorieUse {get;set;}
    double mediumCalorieUse {get;set;}
    double highCalorieUse {get;set;}

    //Then to calculate it, its pretty easy

    public double CalculateCaloriesBurnt(double mass, double time)
    {

        double calories = 0;

        if (mass < 130)
        {
            calories = lowCalorieUse;
        }
        //the rest is fairly obvious

        //...

        //Multiply by the time
        return calories * time;
    }
```

Now in your main code, you use a Dictionary Instead...

```
Dictionary<string, ExerciseActivity>
```

Then you can do something nice like this (note, you WILL need to put in checks)

```
exerciseDict[txtExerciseName.text].CalculateCaloriesBurnt(mass,time);
```

(I realize I went a bit out of the original requirements - I don't use an ArrayList - but this should be much cleaner. If you have any questions feel free to ask)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way you can help me through the problem using ArrayList. I know it is impractical but my assignment is designed that way. I would really like to understand the logic behind it; I am brand new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can infer from your question, you want to use the numeric value at the index of the weight category of the activity.

So I'll guess you have 6 weight types, going from the heaviest to the lightest, and then you select the activity.

You want to return the index from the weight category in the `length` one, (so if the user selected the 2nd weight category, the index will be [1], you'll return the matching `length` category in that index.

Having said that, I would delete your code, and write it from scratch, using **PROPER** names that make sense, and using Object oriented methods.

If you want to read about ArrayLists, please, click this link: [MSDN official ArrayList documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).